# MS Access - Autofill not work in combo box

Tags: ms-access, vba, autofill

I've created a combo box and the data will be populated from SQL Server, but I found that the autofill function of this combo box is not working. Is there any problem in my code ? Thanks.

[image: Screen Capture]

```
   Dim oCon As ADODB.Connection
   Dim oRec As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim strQuery As String

   Set oCon = New ADODB.Connection
   Set oRec = New ADODB.Recordset

   oCon.Open "connection string"

   strQuery = "select statement"

   oRec.Open strQuery, oCon, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

   Me.cbxUser.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
   Set Me.cbxUser.Recordset = oRec
```

---

Updated on 16 Jan 2018

It seems that the problem is resolved by using **ComboBox.AddItem** method. But I don't know why the autofill function is not working when I use `Set Me.cbxUser.Recordset = oRec`

```
Set oRec = oCon.Execute(strQuery)
Me.cbxUser.RowSourceType = "Value List"

Do While Not oRec.EOF
    Me.cbxUser.AddItem (oRec("UserID"))
    oRec.MoveNext
Loop
```

[GIF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RwLC.gif)

Comment: That screenshot is not saying a lot. I don't know what you were expecting to see there

Comment: Combobox `Auto Expand` property is `Yes`?

Comment: Never seen combobox Recordset property before. Could just set RowSource property with strQuery instead of opening recordset object.

Comment: Hi @June7, I've also tried using `RowSource`, but I got this error message: 
Record Source 'select statement' specified on this form or report does not exist.

Comment: Hi @SergeyS. I have already set this property to "Yes"

Comment: Hi @ErikvonAsmuth , what I 'm expecting is: the word "JOHN" will be auto-filled after typing the character "J".

Comment: Well, 'select statement' is not valid SQL. You should get error no matter what property you set. Replace with valid SQL, like `"SELECT YourFieldNameHere FROM YourTableNameHere"`. Also, 'connection string' is not valid. These are just generic placeholders used by whomever wrote that example code. It is example, modify to suit your requirements.

Comment: Try to create pass-through query and use it as `RowSource`, looks like comboboxes with empty `RowSource` property don't support autocomplete

Comment: @June7 using an ADO recordset instead of setting a row source is valid. I sometimes use it to display all tables in an MS SQL database, for example

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Didn't say it wasn't valid, just that I've never seen nor used. But I don't have to work with SQLServer. So I guess the recordset approach is needed if not using linked table or pass-through query.

Comment: @June7 it's really never _needed_, it just avoids needing to store a query when using a passthrough query (and it allows you to use parameterized queries in your record source, which is nice).

Answer (score 0):

The RowSource SQL string must contain the clause "DISTINCT" to make all the business to work (I read this interesting statement in another developer's response in other forum, I tried it and it works)
Also, do not try to transform a list box into a combo box. The properties of the combo box AutoExpand and LimitToList will not convince the combo to work as expected.